# Hadoop Zookeeper understanding

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, nodes, apache-zookeeper

I'm having difficulty understanding the Zookeeper Hadoop framework. The main aspects of zookeeper I find confusing is understanding is how it handles consistency across its nodes, but also how it makes use of its distributed in-memory file system to handle co-ordination? Any help with these points would be great.

Comment: Zookeeper is not related to Hadoop. These are 2 independent technologies.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yann said, Zookeeper is not related to Hadoop. Zookeeper is a coordination engine for services. With it, you can create distributable configuration, service discovery, leader election, among other features.

I suggest you to read this [post](http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2014/07/zookeeper-curator-and-microservices-load-balancing/) to see how it works for load balancing and this [other](http://blog.arungupta.me/zookeeper-microservice-registration-discovery/) for service discovery. Other nice resource to read is [Apache Curator](http://curator.apache.org) that is a framework that make easy to use Zookeeper with Java or any other JVM language